# CSS for fiction ebook

Tags: css, kindle

I am creating a fiction ebook using plain html as the source files for the chapters of the book. I would like to keep the html as vanilla as possible and use CSS for the formatting. Most of the book just needs an indent for any paragraph following a paragraph and every `<hr />` tag should display as a scene break, e.g. 3 * center-aligned.

This all works fine in JSFiddle and in chrome.

```css
p {
  margin: 0rem;
  text-indent: 0rem;
}

p + p {
  text-indent: 1.5rem;
}

hr {
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

hr::after {
  visibility: visible;
  content: "* * *";
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a nunc sit amet ipsum consectetur blandit. Donec vehicula commodo ante vel luctus. Aenean at lobortis velit, quis ultrices orci.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a nunc sit amet ipsum consectetur blandit. Donec vehicula commodo ante vel luctus. Aenean at lobortis velit, quis ultrices orci.</p>
<hr />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a nunc sit amet ipsum consectetur blandit. Donec vehicula commodo ante vel luctus. Aenean at lobortis velit, quis ultrices orci.</p>
```

but when I copy this to the Amazon ebook preview app I need this extra redundant looking CSS for the ***'s to appear ?

```
p::after { 
    content: " "
}
```

Can anyone help identify why this might be needed in the ebook ? I don't want to have to tag a useless space on to the end of every paragraph to make this work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: `<hr>` does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: Maybe you could let it as it is. After all, people won't see this extra space, don't you think ? (this won't help you to resolve the problem... but to reconsider if there is any)

Comment: @Rob in XHTML, it did - hr had a closing slash.

Comment: @Cedric Yes but this is HTML. XHTML is XML.

Comment: Sorry, error in my post the kindle ebook format does expect XHTML and hence the slash on the hr. I called this HTML as when playing to get this to work I just save as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the `visibility: visible` vs. `hidden` combination in the `hr` and its pseudo element: You can simply apply `border: none;` to the `hr` to avoid the display of the horizontal line itself. This might also help with your other problem.

```css
p {
  margin: 0rem;
  text-indent: 0rem;
}

p + p {
  text-indent: 1.5rem;
}

hr {
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

hr::after {
  content: "* * *";
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a nunc sit amet ipsum consectetur blandit. Donec vehicula commodo ante vel luctus. Aenean at lobortis velit, quis ultrices orci.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a nunc sit amet ipsum consectetur blandit. Donec vehicula commodo ante vel luctus. Aenean at lobortis velit, quis ultrices orci.</p>
<hr />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a nunc sit amet ipsum consectetur blandit. Donec vehicula commodo ante vel luctus. Aenean at lobortis velit, quis ultrices orci.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, works in browser but kindle shows no separator at all with this CSS.

Comment: Just for info I should mention, this also works OK if you add the p::after space character fudge.. So if I do live with this as being a strange kindle only issue I will use your version, thanks ;)